# Attempting to extract .img files from a Samsung Rom, how?

Tags: linux, windows, rom

So far i have extracted the files out of system.img and cache.img, but the others dont work, they dont seem to be ext4 or something, i tried 2 roms of different phones and tablets, i was able to extract system.img using simg2img and ext2explore, but the others say `Bad Magic` when attempting to use simg2img on them, 7 zip doesnt work either for any of them nor can i mount any inside Linux.

```
system.img - success
cache.img - success
hidden.img - extracts nothing
boot.img - bad magic
recovery.img - bad magic
SPRDCP.img - bad magic
SPRDDSP.img - bad magic
```

Comment: boot.img is not a file-system it is the boot image containing the kernel image. AFAIK recovery is similar to boot.img just that it in addition contains a very minimal OS, the recovery OS.

Comment: Spreadtrum Core Processor / DSP baseband are proprietary and cannot extracted https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseband_processor#Security_concerns